# KeyboardInterrupt not instant, I need to input an other key, using cmd.Cmd.cmdloop() in python

Tags: python, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I'm trying to make a good handling of KeyboardInterruptey, I want it to clear the console, but when I press Ctrl+C, it doesnt raise the exception, I have to input an other key so it raise it, here is my cmdloop() :

```
import cmd

class MyCommandPrompt(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False

    def emptyline(self) -> None:
        """Do nothing on empty input line"""
        pass

    def cmdloop(self, intro=None):
        """Boucle de commandes"""
        while not self.stop:
            try:
                super().cmdloop(intro="")
                self.postloop()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                os.system("cls")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyCommandPrompt().cmdloop()
```

I have no idea what is wrong with it. I you have any question about about information that you would need I will give them to you, but I think I wrote everything.

I tryed for that to add try except block but it didn't change anythings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here's the FAQ on how to provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)